# Replacing content_scripts - What to choose WebExtension API vs Tabs API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm converting my existing `content_scripts` based extension to `activeTab` permission based.

Along with that I'm also providing `optional_permissions` so that I can ask permission to users to inject my scripts the way it used to be, if user allows.

I'm currently curious to know what route should I take. I know there are two ways, either using `webNavigation` or using `tabs` permission.

For `webNavigation` permission I'm going to use:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(loadCssAndJS, {url: [{urlPrefix : 'http'}]})
```

Also I'm programmatically filtering out the inner frames.

For `tabs` permission I'm going to use:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(loadCssAndJS)
```

I've few questions, if someone can answer:

- Which permission should I choose and why?
- What are some best practices?
- Any considerations I should keep in mind?

Comment: The best method is none of those but browser.contentScripts.register in FF and chrome.declarativeContent + RequestContentScript action in Chrome. In the future Chrome will have a registerContentScript method.

Comment: @wOxxOm I wanted to keep common code for both Firefox and Chrome. That’s why chosen that, I’ll review your suggestion as well.